# what is difference between RedirectToRoutePermanent and RedirectToRoute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

i need help for this question.
what is difference between  RedirectToRoutePermanent and  RedirectToRoute in asp.net core?

Comment: Neither exist in ASP.NET Core, being properties in `System.Web`, which belongs to .NET Framework. Still, if you loop up them in the doc's, it explain their difference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirecttoroutepermanent?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.2

Comment: They do exist in ASP.NET Core. They're both methods of the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoroutepermanent?view=aspnetcore-2.2) class.

Comment: The names are pretty obvious. One redirects and the other redirects permanently. What is not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is the HTTP code returned to the browser:

- [`RedirectToRoutePermanent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoroutepermanent?view=aspnetcore-2.2) returns a 301 HTTP code (Moved Permanently)
- [`RedirectToRoute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoroute?view=aspnetcore-2.2) returns a 302 HTTP code (Moved Temporarily)

The difference is that if you return a 301 HTTP code, the next time the browser tries to connect to the URL, it will directly go the alternative URL (so it will no longer try the old URL).

With a 302 code, the browser will still try to connect to the URL.

You can read more about the difference on Wikipedia :

- [HTTP 301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)
- [HTTP 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)